# Why is logon not automatic when coming from Stack Overflow via the Stack Exchange menu dropdown?

Tags: support, login, auto-login

As logged on in Stack Overflow and clicking the Stack Exchange dropdown (top of window client area, far left) my expectation was to be automatically logged in to Server Fault...

That did not happen ... WHY?

Comment: ...and to answer the upcoming question, I quote this from the answer on the dupe: "and other Q&A sites with their own domain".

Comment: thank you for clarifying.  much appreciated.